# Stata exported tables too wide

Tags: tables, multicolumn, horizontal, wide-image, stata

I have been trying to upload six-column tables to Latex/Overleaf from Stata. Data exported well but I have been struggling to adjust to Latex format, and some columns don't appear as tables are too wide.

The code on Stata to export a six-column table is as follows:

```
*esttab q1_1 q1_2 q1_3 q1_4 q1_5 q1_6 using "$output_tex/fin_4_4_4_q11-q16_tables_ra.tex", ///
replace f /// 
cells(b(fmt(%9.3f)) se(fmt(%9.2f) star par)) star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) ///
keep(1.treatment_status 2.treatment_status) /// what variable to keep 
label booktabs noobs nonotes nomtitle collabels(none)  ///
mgroups("Use of digital payment applications" "Use of digital payment applications for remittances" ///
 "Use of digital payment applications for remittances, conditional on remitting", ///
 pattern(1 0 1 0 1 0) prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) ///
suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span})) ///
stats(N c_mean hascon coef se, fmt(%9.0fc %9.3f %9.3f %9.3f) labels("Number of observations" "Control mean of dependent variable" "Additional Control Variables" " Difference in means (CR) - (I)" "Se (CR)-(I)"))*
```

In a .tex format, the table looks like this:

```
 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Use of digital payment applications}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Use of digital payment applications for remittances}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Use of digital payment applications for remittances, conditional on remitting}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         \\
\midrule
Classroom (CR)      &       0.051         &       0.050         &       0.038         &       0.037         &       0.060         &       0.063         \\
                    &      (0.03)\sym{*}  &      (0.03)\sym{*}  &      (0.03)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} \\
Individualized (I)  &       0.107         &       0.104         &       0.078         &       0.067         &       0.086         &       0.086         \\
                    &      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} \\
\midrule
Number of observations&         615         &         615         &         615         &         615         &         482         &         482         \\
Control mean of dependent variable&       0.060         &       0.060         &       0.050         &       0.050         &       0.060         &       0.060         \\
Additional Control Variables&          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         &          No         &         Yes         \\
 Difference in means (CR) - (I)&      -0.060         &      -0.050         &      -0.040         &      -0.030         &      -0.030         &      -0.020         \\
Se (CR)-(I)         &       0.040         &       0.040         &       0.030         &       0.030         &       0.040         &       0.040         \\
```

Then, on latex the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{dcolumn} % Align on the decimal point of numbers in tabular columns
     \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For better formatting of table notes
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[colorlinks,%
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,%
linkcolor=black,%
urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % for linking between references, figures, TOC, etc in the pdf document
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\let\estinput=\input % define a new input command so that we can still flatten the document

\newcommand{\estwide}[3]{
\vspace{.75ex}{
\textsymbols
\begin{tabular*}
{\textwidth}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{#2}{#3}}
\toprule
\estinput{#1}
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabular*}
}
}

\newcommand{\estauto}[3]{
\vspace{.75ex}{
\textsymbols
\begin{tabular}{l*{#2}{#3}}
\toprule
\estinput{#1}
\bottomrule
\addlinespace[.75ex]
\end{tabular}
}
}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
}
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{\rlap{#1}}

\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
        input-signs     = ,
        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ] - + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        }
        

    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Impact of treatment on use of digital payment applications and use of digital payment applications for remittances.} \label{table}
    \small\estwide{fin_4_4_4_q11-q16_tables_ra.tex}{6}{c} 
    \Fignote{Notes: - Standard errors in parentheses (*** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1). \\
    - The control mean of dependent variable is the non-attrited subsample mean at baseline. \\
    - All regressions include a constant, the outcome variable at baseline, as well as strata fixed effects. Additional control variables, when included, are: Age, Native state, Marital Status,  Financial stress index at baseline, Remittance dummy at baseline,  Monthly remittance quantity at baseline, Use of digital payment applications at baseline. \\
    - All regressions are weighted with the Inverse Predicted Probability from Probit of Attrition on Treatments, with strata, outcome at baseline, and the additional control variables included.}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{table}
```

I have also tried the horizontal option :

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
\caption{Impact of treatment on use of digital payment applications and use of digital payment applications for remittances.}
   \label{table}
\small\estwide{fin_4_4_4_q11-q16_tables_ra.tex}{6}{c} 
\Fignote{Notes: - Standard errors in parentheses (*** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1). \\
- The control mean of dependent variable is the non-attrited subsample mean at baseline. \\
- All regressions include a constant, the outcome variable at baseline, as well as strata fixed effects. Additional control variables, when included, are: Age, Native state, Marital Status,  Financial stress index at baseline, Remittance dummy at baseline,  Monthly remittance quantity at baseline, Use of digital payment applications at baseline. \\
- All regressions are weighted with the Inverse Predicted Probability from Probit of Attrition on Treatments, with strata, outcome at baseline, and the additional control variables included.}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Below, you can see how the tables appear:
[image]
[image]

Do you happen to know how this table could be reduced/fit into one page with all columns included?
Thank you very much in advance for your help.
Best regards,
Raphaëlle Aulagnon

Comment: Introduce linebreaks in the multicolumn headers to make your table narrower.

Comment: Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Currently, the documentclass, the relevant packages as well as the contents of the table itself are missing.

Comment: Related: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: Please use the edit button to add this information directly into your question. In the comments, people might overlook it.

Comment: thank you @leandriis! hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
%%\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%\usepackage{lscape} 
%%\usepackage{dcolumn} % Align on the decimal point of numbers in tabular columns
%%     \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For better formatting of table notes
%%\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


%%\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
%%\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}
%%}
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\fignote}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Note:~}~#1}}

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{\figtext{\emph{Source:~}~#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx} % centering in tables
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing       = true,
        group-digits        = false ,
%        input-signs     = ,
%        input-symbols       = ( ) [ ]  + *,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-post   = false
        }
        
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{nosep, 
                    left=0pt,
                    before=\begin{minipage}{\linewidth},
                    after =\end{minipage}, 
                    label=--}

\usepackage[colorlinks,%
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,%
linkcolor=black,%
urlcolor=black]{hyperref} % for linking between references, figures, TOC, etc in the pdf document

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \sisetup{table-format=-1.3,
           table-space-text-pre=),
           table-space-text-post=)***,
           table-align-text-pre=false,
           table-align-text-post=false}
           \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \caption{Impact of treatment on use of digital payment applications and use of digital payment applications for remittances.} \label{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{6}{S}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\thead{Use of digital payment applications}}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{total}
       &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{for remittances}}
         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{ for remittances, condi-\\tional on remitting}}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7} 
  &{(1)} &{(2)} &{(3)} &{(4)} &{(5)}  &{(6)}         \\
\midrule
Classroom (CR)      &       0.051         &       0.050         &       0.038         &       0.037         &       0.060         &       0.063         \\
                    &      (0.03)\sym{*}  &      (0.03)\sym{*}  &      (0.03)         &      (0.03)         &      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} \\
Individualized (I)  &       0.107         &       0.104         &       0.078         &       0.067         &       0.086         &       0.086         \\
                    &      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{***}&      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} &      (0.03)\sym{**} \\
\midrule
Number of observations&         {615}         &        {615}         &        {615}         &         {615}         &         {482}         &         {482}         \\
Control mean of dependent variable&       0.060         &       0.060         &       0.050         &       0.050         &       0.060         &       0.060         \\
Additional Control Variables&          {No}         &         {Yes}         &          {No        } &         {Yes}         &          {No}         &        { Yes}         \\
 Difference in means (CR) - (I)&      -0.060         &      -0.050         &      -0.040         &      -0.030         &      -0.030         &      -0.020         \\
Se (CR)-(I)         &       0.040         &       0.040         &       0.030         &       0.030         &       0.040         &       0.040         \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
Notes: 

\begin{myitemize}
\item Standard errors in parentheses (*** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1). 
\item The control mean of dependent variable is the non-attrited subsample mean at baseline.
\item All regressions include a constant, the outcome variable at baseline, as well as strata fixed effects. Additional control variables, when included, are: Age, Native state, Marital Status,  Financial stress index at baseline, Remittance dummy at baseline,  Monthly remittance quantity at baseline, Use of digital payment applications at baseline. 
\item All regressions are weighted with the Inverse Predicted Probability from Probit of Attrition on Treatments, with strata, outcome at baseline, and the additional control variables included.
\end{myitemize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is extremely helpful! 
Raphaëlle